# while and foreach loop with array

Tags: php, arrays

I am making a cart for my project. First the guest (not logged in) will choose products from the category that will be stored on SESSIONS. Second the guest will log in. I want all items from SESSION to be stored in users database or if existing, update.

This is my code:

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    //Log
    $core->testLog("Database Product: " . $row['product_id']);
    foreach($_SESSION['product_checkout_list'] as $key => $value) {

        //Log
        $core->testLog("- Array Product: " . $_SESSION['product_checkout_list'][$key]['checkID']);
        if($value['checkID'] == $row['product_id']) {
            $insert = $core->prepare("UPDATE on_cart SET user_id = :uid, qty = :qty, stamp = :stamp WHERE product_id = :prod_id");

            $insert->bindParam(":uid", $_SESSION['user']['id']);
            $insert->bindParam(":prod_id", $value['checkID']);
            $insert->bindParam(":qty", $value['checkQty']);
            $insert->bindparam(":stamp", $timestamp);
            $insert->execute();

            //Log
            $core->testLog("-- " . $value['checkID'] . " is equal to " . $row['product_id']);
        } else {
            $insert = $core->prepare("INSERT INTO on_cart VALUES(null, :uid, :prod_id, :qty, :stamp);");
            $insert->bindParam(":uid", $_SESSION['user']['id']);
            $insert->bindParam(":prod_id", $value['checkID']);
            $insert->bindParam(":qty", $value['checkQty']);
            $insert->bindparam(":stamp", $timestamp);
            $insert->execute();

            //Log
            $core->testLog("-- " . $value['checkID'] . " is not equal to " . $row['product_id']);

        }

        unset($_SESSION['product_checkout_list'][$key]);

            // Log
            foreach($_SESSION['product_checkout_list'] as $key => $value) {
                $core->testLog("--- " . $value['checkID']);
            }

        break;
    }
}
```

My Log is this :

```
03/20/2018 - 10:36:21 PM : Database Product: 1
03/20/2018 - 10:36:21 PM : - Array Product: 1
03/20/2018 - 10:36:21 PM : -- 1 is equal to 1
03/20/2018 - 10:36:21 PM : --- 2
03/20/2018 - 10:36:21 PM : --- 4
03/20/2018 - 10:36:21 PM : Database Product: 2
03/20/2018 - 10:36:21 PM : - Array Product: 2
03/20/2018 - 10:36:21 PM : -- 2 is equal to 2
03/20/2018 - 10:36:21 PM : --- 4
```

My problem is that the last product which is 4 - is being skipped because of break. But if I remove the break, the `$row['product_id']` will not be refreshed (it will stay on 1 until everything's complete). Like this:

```
03/20/2018 - 10:38:57 PM : Database Product: 1
03/20/2018 - 10:38:57 PM : - Array Product: 1
03/20/2018 - 10:38:57 PM : -- 1 is equal to 1
03/20/2018 - 10:38:57 PM : --- 2
03/20/2018 - 10:38:57 PM : --- 4
03/20/2018 - 10:38:57 PM : - Array Product: 2
03/20/2018 - 10:38:57 PM : -- 2 is not equal to 1
03/20/2018 - 10:38:57 PM : --- 4
03/20/2018 - 10:38:57 PM : - Array Product: 4
03/20/2018 - 10:38:57 PM : -- 4 is not equal to 1
03/20/2018 - 10:38:57 PM : Database Product: 2
```

What I want to happen is that guest or users can choose first their products before logging in. If the user has logged in, the system will check if the user has items on SESSION cart and insert it on the database or update the existing one. I've been thinking about the solution 2 days ago and I can't get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to always avoid using break on anything else than switch blocks.

Also, you are doing the search the opposite way. You need to, for every product that is in the array, check if it is on the db. Take a look:

```
// Will only populate an array for easier search
$dbItems = array();
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $dbItems[] = $row;
}

//Log
foreach($_SESSION['product_checkout_list'] as $key => $value) {

    //Log
    $core->testLog("- Array Product: " . $_SESSION['product_checkout_list'][$key]['checkID']);
    // Flag to mark if the item is on the db or not
    $found = false;

    foreach($dbItems as $row) {
        if($value['checkID'] == $row['product_id']) {
            $insert = $core->prepare("UPDATE on_cart SET user_id = :uid, qty = :qty, stamp = :stamp WHERE product_id = :prod_id");

            $insert->bindParam(":uid", $_SESSION['user']['id']);
            $insert->bindParam(":prod_id", $value['checkID']);
            $insert->bindParam(":qty", $value['checkQty']);
            $insert->bindparam(":stamp", $timestamp);
            $insert->execute();

            //Log
            $core->testLog("-- Found " . $value['checkID'] . " in db as " . $row['product_id']);
            // Flag it as found, so we will not insert it
            $found = true;
        } 
    }
    // Not found on the db? Lets insert it
    if(!$found) {
        $insert = $core->prepare("INSERT INTO on_cart VALUES(null, :uid, :prod_id, :qty, :stamp);");
        $insert->bindParam(":uid", $_SESSION['user']['id']);
        $insert->bindParam(":prod_id", $value['checkID']);
        $insert->bindParam(":qty", $value['checkQty']);
        $insert->bindparam(":stamp", $timestamp);
        $insert->execute();

        //Log
        $core->testLog("-- Product " . $value['checkID'] . " was not on the db");

    }
}

// Empty the session array
$_SESSION['product_checkout_list'] = array();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!